# Audio/Video conferencing for iOS, Android & Web Platform

Tags: video, chat, quickblox, video-conferencing, opentok

I am working on application where I need to integrate text & video chat and video conferencing feature. 
I found that you guys provides solutions for that and I am very much interested in using/integrating your platform for my application.

I have following concerns for using your platform.  I want text & video chat and video conferencing available on iOS, Android and Web Platform.

I can only find following for my purpose :
iOS Platform :
 http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-videochat-ios

Android Platform :
 https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-android

Web Platform :
on website its written that "Web (+Facebook) SDK is now under development." and I didn't found any link for this too.   So, Please send me link if video conferencing is possible using your platform.

Please, let me know is it possible to have multiple user video chat, i.e. video conferencing for all 3 platforms (iOS, Android & Web)? 
Is there any good SDK available for all 3 platforms?

**I have just found 2 things 
1) http://quickblox.com/
2) http://tokbox.com/**

**Please suggest me which one is better for my purpose. Also suggest me if there is any good tool available for this.**

Please let me know about it as soon as possible because I am working on tight deadline project and I need to finalize the platform ASAP.

Comment: for quickblox integrations have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47117314/2437655

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple options with TokBox: our OpenTok on WebRTC stack, or our older OpenTok (with Flash) stack. In both cases you can create a video streaming solution across web, iOS, and android, but they both have different caveats.

**OpenTok on WebRTC**
JavaScript (web): http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/webrtc/docs
iOS: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-webrtc
Android: use Chrome on Android, reuse web application

**OpenTok (Flash)**
JavaScript (web): http://tokbox.com/opentok/docs/
iOS: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk
Android: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk

In general, WebRTC is the real future of the technology, so its probably wise to start building for longevity on that. If you are really concerned about support for older browsers, start your application with the Flash stack and make the switch when you are ready, its as simple as swapping out the library or the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

TokBox, as of today, only provides the video streaming aspect. You can use text chat with another api like https://www.firebase.com/. Heres an example of an app built on both TokBox and Firebase to have video and text chat: http://opentokrtc.com/